# How to invert sound coming in through speakers and play it back?

Tags: windows, audio

Hi I know in Audacity you can record a sound, invert it, and then play it, but I'm looking for something automatic.

Basically this program would listen to all sound coming in, invert them, and then play them at the same time. All instantly. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to switch the wires between the + and - terminals on the speakers?

Comment: No no I want to invert the sound so it will sound muted to anyone hearing it.

Comment: So, you mean that you want to create a noise cancelling device?

Comment: Yeah but on Windows with software.

Answer (score 0):

This will be nearly impossible. You will need ASIO or another driver with ultra low latency, and even then it might not be fast enough.

It would be much easier to get a pair of headphones that'll cancel out external audio by itself and play some music or gray noise through it.

I got myself a pair of Sennheiser CX300II expecially for this purpose. Will work with any device, including your smartphone.

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do is write a reverse-mute bot for my TeamSpeak server. Basically I'll log in another client that has everyone muted so when Guests join and they talk I'd broadcast the inverse of their speech to everyone else so they're effectively muted.

Comment: @JohnJohnson: This is useful clarification.  Please edit your question to include the information that you have written as comments.

Comment: The way you want to do this will not work. When the audio of the person is broadcasted to the server, and to everyone, including the bot, it will take too much time before the new counter signal is sent back to everyone, so the delay will basically cause an echo rather than cancelling the sound. You'll need to look into blocking people from the server level. I believe you can setup moderated channels and assign if someone has Voice rights to talk or not at all, and make channels require a password. So I'd create a default channel that no one can talk into, and they have to move to talk.